# PHP: can't get form value to the class

Tags: php, forms, null

I got simple html form, each input that comes from this form I would like to filtr. First I couldn't parse function result to a string, then I realize the reason is that the result is NULL. It seems like the data from the form is not transfererd to the class (?). Can you please give me a hint - why?

**Form on index.php**

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="textbox" name="nrInput" maxlength="5000"> 
    <input type="Submit" name="myForm" value="Go">
</form>

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');                             
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['myForm']) {

    $number = (empty($_POST['nrInput'])) ? die('Please enter a value.') : $_POST['nrInput'] ;
    require ('class.forminput.php'); 
    $number = new formInput(); //?
    $number->trimInput($number);
    echo $number;
}
?>
```

**class.forminput.php**

```
class formInput {

    public $costam;

    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this->costam;
    }

    public function trimInput($costam)
    {
        if(is_null($this->costam)) 
        {
        return 'Empty';
        }

        $costam = trim($this->$costam);
        $costam = str_replace(';', ',', $this->$costam);
        $costam = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-,]/', '', $this->$costam);
        $costam = trim(preg_replace('/(,|-)\1+/','$1', $this->$costam), ',');
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        if(is_null($this->costam)) 
        {
        return 'Empty';
        }

        return $this->costam;
    }


}
```

The result is 'Empty'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, PHP constructor returns nothing, so a `return` in a constructor will never be issued.

**Second**, you should pass the paramenter to it if you want to assign to the class property.

```
public function __construct($input)
{
   $this->costam = $input;
}
```

It's the `trimInput()` that needs return something:

```
public function trimInput()
{
   $costam = trim($this->costam);
   $costam = str_replace(';', ',', $costam);
   $costam = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-,]/', '', $costam);
   $costam = trim(preg_replace('/(,|-)\1+/','$1', $costam), ',');
   return $costam;
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
$number = new formInput($_POST['nrInput']);
$result = $number->trimInput();
echo $result;
```

Note also that your input will never be `NULL`

Comment: Thanks Damien, you helped me a lot. OOP is now a little less horrible ;)